# Access to ASP:Textbox on http handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to use the MultiUpload flash script on my ASP / VB.NET project and, to upload a file (following the instruction available on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx) I created an HTTP Handler. It works fine but, at this point, I need to read a value from a ASP:Textbox available on the caller page. How can I read this parameter?

thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the value of the textbox along with the request. You could use the `QueryParameters` property of the `FlashUpload` control. Inside the upload handler you would then simply read the request value: `context.Request["paramName"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you're submitting to the handler, but you can pass it in as either part of a query string or in the FormData if you're posting to the server. Then you can access this value in the `HttpContext.Request` object